# Why the edge of iOS app icon is lacked?

Tags: ios, iphone, image

When I test app, called "Kenja" on iOS simulator, the icon view clearly, however I test it at real device(iPhone 5s) the edge of icon is lacked as following pictures. I've followed the selected size shown on the third picture.  Could you tell me what is the problem? Thank you for your kindness.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please describe what edge is lacking? I can see two similar icons on very different backdrops.

Comment: They look the same to me.  Try changing the wallpaper on the simulator (via the Photos app) to something lighter.

Comment: The corners of your icon are always going to be rounded.  My suggestion would be to create a new image with more padding on the edges to compensate for the rounded corners

Comment: Thank you. I'll try these advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the developer guide for making app icons.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html

"When iOS displays an app icon on the Home screen of a device, it automatically applies a mask that rounds the corners. Make sure your icon has 90° corners so it looks good after the mask is applied"

Comment: Their icons *are* square.  The issue is that the corners are being clipped since they're outside the rounding mask.